Converting Bitmap to text with as less characters as possible C#
I am using an API call to store the data of some receipts and I want to extend the functionality and be able to somehow store an image that will be used as a signature for the receipt. I tried to store the image in a Bitmap property I created, but I found out that there's a problem with bitmaps and serialization/deserialization in JSON. I also tried to store the bytes of the image, but I had a significantly large amount of bytes (800.000) and there was a problem sending that info into the server.
Does anybody have a recommendation on how to store an image that could be store with less characters and be serializable/deserializable?
I tried getting the bytes of the img and converting them in a Base64 string but it didn't help (it only increased the size of the characters)

"How do I send the same information with less bytes" sounds like the age old problem of compression or using a more optimized storage format.

Do you actually need the complete image for anything? If you just want to use it to generate a signature, you should research hashing. There's a good (and very short) introduction to the topic here

It is not really clear what you mean by "signature for the receipt". If a user takes two images of the same receipt, would you expect the same signature? What purpose does the signature serve?

In the case of shipping labels (image): we byte stream the image to the server and save it (as a file) with a GUID. The "shipping record" itself is stored in the "database" with the GUID of the related shipping label (file). The labels can be viewed on the server (the clients are kiosks where the actual printing took place).
